# jQuery and Ninja Forms WordPress Plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, ninja

I want to change the value of a Ninja Form input with jQuery, eg:

```
$('#ninja_forms_field_6').val(somevalue);
```

But this just wont work, probably because values and calculations are done in the back by PHP.

A + B gives me the Total

What I want is ether to have jQuery "auto type" text into field or to extract given value of the total input.

I said "auto type" because A and B values are being calculated only when I manually type them on keyboard. When I used `$('#ninja_forms_field_6').val(somevalue)` - the value shows up as if it is typed but calculation does not happen.
The other solution for me is to get the calculated value/text that shows up in the Total input after calculation, but as you can see in the image the input tag stays empty.

```
<input id="ninja_forms_field_8" name="ninja_forms_field_8" value="0" disabled="" class="ninja-forms-field " rel="8" type="text"></input>
```

Input for the total stays empty whether its showing the result or not.

If you can help me with this, you would have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Is `somevalue` defined? Did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: please read my question again, I have provided more detail about the problem.

http://s9.postimg.org/7vb91u09r/ninja.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger a "change" event after changing the value of the field:

```
$('#ninja_forms_field_6').trigger("change");
```

That worked for me in some select fields, I don't know if it will work on other types of fields. Maybe trying some other jquery event type will work if "change" does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change a field in Ninja Forms 3.2.1,  it appears that Ninja Forms 3 has changed `#ninja_forms_field_` to `#nf-field-` as documented here: http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/changing-field-values/

I have not been able to successfully change a field in Ninja Forms 3.x and I would appreciate any tips from those who have been successful.